# Run multiple find command over ssh on different hosts in BASH

Tags: bash, unix, ssh, batch-processing

Hello working on the bash script that will ssh to multiple boxes and execute some diskspace cleaning commands. I am using find and ssh  is passwordless. I have approximately 10 boxes in the list. But I am failing with the logic. Here is the code:

```
  #!/bin/bash

#cleanup_paths
NUMLINE=$(cat /hostnames.txt|wc -l)
SERVER_LIST=/hostnames.txt
CPATH1=/random_files
CPATH2=/random_files1
CPATH3=/random_files2
CPATH4=/random_files3
CPATH5=/random_files4
CPATH6=/random_files5
CPATH7=/random_files6
MAX_DISK=86

while read line;
do

ssh $line

CURRENT_USAGE=$(df -h|grep /home|awk '{print $4}'|sed 's/%//')

cleanup_engage(){
      if [ $CURRENT_USAGE -ge $MAX_DISK ]; then
         return 1
      else
         return 0
      fi
}

cleanup_engage

     if [ "$?" -eq "1" ]; then
        find $CPATH1 -type f  -name '*.log' -mtime +3 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 20
        find $CPATH2 -maxdepth 1 -type d  -name 'FTS*' -mtime +5 -exec rm -rf {} \;
     sleep 30
        find $CPATH3 -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 5
        find $CPATH4 -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 5
        find $CPATH5 -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 5
        find $CPATH6 -type f -name '*.log' -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 5
        find $CPATH7 -type f -name '*LOG*' -mtime +5 -exec rm -f {} \;
     sleep 10

/usr/bin/sendmail stack@stack.com<<EOF
subject: 


EOF
    else
    exit 0
fi
((NUMLINE++))
done < $SERVER_LIST
```

Answer (score 0):

When your script executes the "ssh" line, ssh establishes a connection to the remote host and opens a shell.But that shell knows nothing about your script. It's just a shell, waiting for input, and your script is waiting for ssh to terminate so it can get on to the next line...

It looks like you are trying to ssh somewhere, and then execute some bash commands on the remote host. You can do something like this:

ssh $someremotehost << EOT
(shell commands to be run on the remote host)
EOT

Remember, the shell opened on the remote host is a brand new shell, and will know nothing about what is in the script running on your local host. So you need to feed a comlete script to the remote side.

Play around with it and have fun...